# Data source parameters in main report evaluated twice

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a main report with 2 sub reports in it.I have two data sources( as json restful service).
Now I made two parameters in main report which hold the above data sources.
I passed one each parameter to each of the two sub reports.
But the problem is - when I deploy and run the report in jasper server - the two parameters are evaluated twice each. Means my json restful services are called four times (two for each parameter).

I have some filters also attached to all the services which are configured as input controls - these have some default values and are part of my restful service data source URL...BUT when I change any filter - the services run exacatly once for each.

Thus in nut shell - first run of report evaluates the parameters twice but after first run if i just change filters it runs one time for each service.

can someone please throw some light on it - I want that each data source param should be evaluated just once - as it takes time for my service to return data.

Comment: What band do you have your sub reports in? Does the band get evaluated twice and so the sub report does too? Try to create a small example that only shows your problem. Either that solves it for you as you see your problem or it enables us to understand where you went off track.

Comment: The sub reports are in summary band...the jist of problem is - I create a parameter which has data source in main report and pass it to sub report. On run of report the parameter gets evaluated twice 'coz of which there is overall performance hit.

Comment: The problem is that stuff only gets evaluated twice if it is placed twice. This is straight on debugging work and can't be meaningfully answered here I fear. Please do post some kind of structured information on how the report is set up. Most likely its a language barrier but the words you use don't form meaning in my head. Create and post a simple self sufficient runnable example that shows the problem. It should include: 1 Parameter, 1 DataSource, 2 Subreports that each show 1 Field. Then include whatever gets run twice in the place were its in your report. Then post it.

Comment: @sujeet
Are you use Table in subreports?
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/823901/why-incrementer-runs-twice